# How to create a destructor for a class

Tags: c++, class, destructor

I see that for many classes the destructor is empty. However, this is not the case for all. Is there a rule on when we need to write something inside the destructor? If all our variables in the class are static, do we always just need an empty destructor?

Comment: If you need a destructor, write one. If you don't, don't? If you see a destructor, look at the code and see what it does. It's probably needed.

Comment: If you want to do something when the object is destroyed, then you need a destructor. That's what a destructor *is*.

Comment: Also, if all variables in the class are static, then why do you even have a class?

Answer (score 1):

You need a destructor when you need to do something when an item is destroyed. There is no standard thing you might need to do with a destructor.

**Things you might choose to use a destructor for:**

1. Terminate some running threads.
2. Provide a meaningful message to the user.
3. Print something important to a file, which will be lost after the item get deleted.
4. Deallocate memory using `delete` (memory which has been allocated using the `new` operator).
5. Close an internet connection socket.

While a `destructor` is an automated way of doing a job for each item, you might opt to do those tasks "manually", either in the main body of the program (not recommended) or by using specific methods for doing so.

Comment: If I do not have any private variables in my class on the heap do I still need to deallocate memory using delete in the destructor?

Comment: You use delete only for memory you have allocated using new.

Answer (score 0):

If  you don't define any constructor then c++ will create an empty default constructor for you.

So the answer is that you are free to decided whether to define or not to define an empty constructor. It doesn't make any difference in this case.

If all variables of class are static... It depends heavily on the situation but usually as a rule of thumb static classes don't use  destructors because they are not instantiated like "normal" classes.

Sometimes it happens that you do need to have all variables in class static. 
There is even a [pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) for such situation. But this is more as an exception rather than a rule.